# что вы советуйте?

Tags: laravel

использовать в laravel **migration** или управлять из база данных

Comment: Однозначно миграции

Comment: Лучше использовать миграции. Но если сильно лень заводить миграцию на какую-то мелочь, то можно и из самой базы поправить (но обязательно дописать в какую-нибудь предыдущую миграцию подходящую, иначе потом поднимать всё это дело где-нибудь ещё будет затруднительно)...

Answer (score 0):

На Миграции Ларавел принято смотреть как на систему контроля версий БД, они помогают быстро развернуть проект, отредактировать таблицы и во время разработки в командах их требуют, поэтому однозначно советую!

Принципиально ларавел будет работать и без миграций! Но это серьёзно усложнит взаимодействие с таблицами БД.